# What regex will match every character except comma ',' or semi-colon ';'?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to define a regex which will match every character except a certain defined character or set of characters?

Basically, I wanted to split a string by either comma (,) or semi-colon (;). So I was thinking of doing it with a regex which would match everything until it encountered a comma or a semi-colon.

Answer (score 594, accepted):

```
[^,;]+
```

You haven't specified the regex implementation you are using. Most of them have a `Split` method that takes delimiters and split by them. You might want to use that one with a "normal" (without `^`) character class:

```
[,;]+
```

Comment: And the question doesn't specify whether adjacent separators are allowed, so the trailing '+' is slightly dubious.

Comment: Getting an error only for semicolon-- unterminated regexp meets end of file

Comment: I had a similar requirement where I want to avoid semicolon and comma at the end I tried a lot but no success below is the Regex I am using const regexDomain = /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9]/g; Well it validates if I use , and ; in between but fails at the end to vliadate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the trailing '+' gives you the exact match, check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/5d7853944b78) if you remove it you will match every characters.

Answer (score 107):

Use character classes. A character class beginning with caret will match anything not in the class.

```
[^,;]
```

Comment: More about [negated character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: I had a similar requirement where I want to avoid semicolon and comma at the end I tried a lot but no success below is the Regex I am using           
const regexDomain = /^(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9]/g;              Well it validates if I use , and ; in between but fails at the end to vliadate.

Comment: @Harry this regex works if you want to avoid  the semicolon and comma at the end, check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/regex-tester/dacc74f04525).

Answer (score 56):

Use a [negative character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
[^,;]+
```

This will match at least one character that is not a comma nor a semicolon. If there are multiple characters matching this criterion, all of them will be matched (`+` at-least-once quantifier)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
([^,;]*[,;])*
```

Comment: That requires the comma or semi-colon as a field delimiter, rather than as a field separator.  The difference matters at the end of a 'line' (or other scanned record structure); typically, you don't want to insist on a comma or semi-colon after the last field.  If your regex engine is powerful enough, you can use '`(?:([^,;]*)(?:[^,;]|$))`' (PCRE with non-capturing parentheses).  The alternatives of a comma or semi-colon after the field, or end of record, makes things work better.  Also consider whether empty fields are allowed.

Comment: Finally, you have to worry about what is actually returned by the captures - did you really want the separators included, and if there are 10 fields on a line, how many of them are returned by the capture notation.

Comment: You are right about all that but the reason I didn't concert those thing in my answer is that I do not know what language/library of RegEx the questioner is asking. He may be using "GREP". Anyway, I appreciate you adding those comments to clear things up for him. :D