# gsub() everything except specified characters?

Tags: regex, r

How do I gsub() everything except a specified character in R?

In my problem I have the following string...

```
"the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog"
```

I have to generate a new string with by removing all characters except 'r' and 'o' and get the following output...

```
"roooro"
```

Assuming all characters are lower case how do I go about. I tried...

```
gsub(!"r","",gsub(!"o","",str1))
```

But the '!' doesn't work.

Comment: See 
[*What regex will match every character except comma ',' or semi-colon ';'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409162/what-regex-will-match-every-character-except-comma-or-semi-colon).

Comment: Actually, I would not call it an exact dupe of the post above since the characters and actual requirements (use of a vector) make this question different (well, not sure if unique :)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We need to use `^` inside the `[` to match all characters except the `ro`.  Here, the `[^ro]+` implies matching one or more characters that are not a 'r' or 'o' and replace it with blank (`""`).

```
gsub("[^ro]+", "", str1)
#[1] "roooro"
```

---

If we have a vector of values, we can create the pattern with `paste`

```
v1 <- c("r", "o")
gsub(paste0("[^", paste(v1, collapse=""), "]+"), "", str1)
#[1] "roooro"
```

Comment: Thanks arkun... this works for me... however is there any way to specify 'r' and 'o' as a vector instead of directly specifying them in gsub command.

Comment: @Gaurav I believe you have a vector of values, in that case use `paste` (updated the post)

Comment: FYI: With that `paste` approach, one should watch out for `]`, ``\`` and `-` symbols that might mean something different or close the class prematurely.

Comment: How would this work if you would like to remove everything but "ro", so not the two characters separately?

Comment: @Michael Did you meant `gsub("(ro)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.", "", str1, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun Yes that works! Not sure how it works yet, but I guess that is Googleable.