# Regular Expression: Why do I get no match found

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a document that consists of many sections.

Each section begins with `:[]:` followed by blank space, followed by 1 or more characters (any characters), followed by a `:` a blank space and one or more characters (any characters).

Here's an example:

```
:[]: Abet1, Abetted34: Find the usage in table under section 1-CB-45: Or more info from the related section starting with PARTIE-DU-CORPS.
:[]: Ou est-ce que tu a mal: Tu as mal aux jambes: Find usage in section 145-TT-LA-TETE.
```

The token of interest from each section is everything from `:[]:` to the first occurrence of `:`. For example, in the first section, I am only interested in extracting: `:[]: Abet1, Abetted34:`

---

At first, I used the following pattern finder to extract the token from each section of the document but this extracted everything from the first occurrence of `:` to the last occurrence of `:` in the section:

```
"\\B:\\[\\]:.*:\\B"
```

If I change the pattern finder to the following to extract the token from `:[]:` to the first occurrence of `:`, I get no match:

```
"\\B:\\[\\]:\\s*.:{1}"
```

How would the regular expression that extracts what I want look like?

Comment: When you say that `:[]: _` (underscore is a space) should be followed by *any* character until the first `:`, you're negating yourself. Clearly, *any* character won't do since `:` is also a character.

Comment: That's correct the ':' is also considered any character but I have tried so many variations and not sure how to exclude ':' from any characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you want?

[image: (?<=:[]: ).*?(?=:)]

See more : https://regex101.com/r/jOmnSb/2

Or

[image: :[]:.*?:]

See more : https://regex101.com/r/jOmnSb/3

UPDATE :

You can convert regex to Java regex here : https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Java regexes need an extra escaping though

Comment: yeah, I found a site to convert regex to java regex : https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd pattern is the one I want. The first one drops the ":" after abetted

Answer (score 3):

So you want to match a string against:

1. `:[]:_` (where `_` is a space character)
2. followed by one or more characters that are not a `:` (refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1409162/6367213) question)
3. close the match with a `:` character

The regex for that would be:

```
:\[\]: [^:]+:
```

You have to escape `\` characters when converting the regex pattern to Java. You could do something like:

```
import java.util.regex.*; 
public class MatchTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(":\\[\\]: [^:]+:", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher =
            pattern.matcher(
                ":[]: Abet1, Abetted34: Find the usage in table under section 1-CB-45: Or more info from the related section starting with PARTIE-DU-CORPS.\n"
              + ":[]: Ou est-ce que tu a mal: Tu as mal aux jambes: Find usage in section 145-TT-LA-TETE."
            );
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted. When I tried this yesterday, instead of [^:]*:", I was using [^:].*:", and didn't know that '*' can be used alone without the '.'