# Regex - Match everything except specified characters or split the string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using this Regex `[^,]+` that matches groups of non-commas but it needs to do this also for characters `;` , `\n` and `empty space`.

I have this string `12f3,,   456;;;;\n\n227-   ,    999` from which I need to get all the substrings like `12f3` , `456`, `227-` and `999`.

Is there a way of matching everything except some specified characters, or is best to use split in this situation?

Comment: So add them to the regex, `/[^\s;,]+/g`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For \s I'm getting 'Unrecognized escape sequence'

Comment: So you using old version of Java, right? Or are you coding in C#?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew C#

Comment: Then use `@"[^\s;,]+"`, see the answer for more details and demos.

Comment: Of course, `[;,]` is not an answer to this question. The requirements are not the same for this and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409162).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *match* these substrings with `[^\s;,]+` pattern. Splitting with `[\s;,]+` is not recommended as there are often empty strings in the resulting array after splitting (due to either matches at the start/end of string, or consecutive matches).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dvuoGN/1).

In C#, use

```cs
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"[^\s;,]+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

The `[^\s;,]+` matches one or more (due to `+` quantifier) occurrences of any char other than (`[^...]` is a *negated* character class) a whitespace (`\s`), semi-colona dn a comma.

**Non-regex approach**

You can split your string with comma and semi-colon, remove empty entries and then trim the strings in the resulting array:

```cs
var text = "12f3,,   456;;;;\n\n227-   ,    999";
var res = text.Split(new[] {";", ","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => x.Trim());
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", res));
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/zkVnmJ). Output:

```cs
12f3
456
227-
999
```